# E2171 Variable 'NyitIdo_oraS' inaccessible here due to optimization

Tags: string, delphi, int, delphi-xe5

Ill got an optimization error dont know why please look on my code
The variable is used only here at 1 time (NyitIdo_oraS and NyitIdo_percS)
No problem with these var. ZarIdo_oraS and ZarIdo_percS
Edit1.text := 06:00-22:00

```
  NyitIdo:=Edit1.Text;
  NyitOraC1 := NyitIdo[1];
  NyitOraC2 := NyitIdo[2];
  NyitPercC1 := NyitIdo[4];
  NyitPercC2 := NyitIdo[5];
  NyitIdo_oraS := StrToInt(NyitOraC1+NyitOraC2)*3600;
  NyitIdo_percS := StrToInt(NyitPercC1+NyitPercC2)*60;


  ZarOraC1 := NyitIdo[7];
  ZarOraC2 := NyitIdo[8];
  ZarPercC1 := NyitIdo[10];
  ZarPercC2 := NyitIdo[11];
  ZarIdo_oraS := StrToInt(ZarOraC1+ZarOraC2)*3600;
  ZarIdo_percS := StrToInt(ZarPercC1+ZarPercC2)*60;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `NyitIdo_oraS` is written to but then never read from. The optimiser can discern that from the code and is at liberty to elide that variable. The call to `StrToInt` still has to be made in case it has side-effects, but there's no reason for the compiler to create the `NyitIdo_oraS` variable since the subsequent code does not refer to it. And similarly for `NyitIdo_percS`.

Usually if you disable optimisations in the compiler settings, this sort of optimisation no longer happens, and you can inspect your variables in the debugger.

If you have warnings enabled then the compiler should inform you that you are assigning to a variable but then never reading the value. Do you have warnings enabled?

Comment: I'll made a trick just gave them some value...
And also thanks for the tip

Comment: Yeah, sometimes that happens.  I suspect those warnings (and the related opt.) are better controllable for simple types.